# Understanding DAG in spark

Tags: java, scala, apache-spark

The question is I have the following DAG:

[image]

I thought that spark devides a job in different stages when shuffling is required. Consider Stage 0 and Stage 1. There are operation which do not require shuffling. So why does Spark split them into different stages?

I thought that actual moving of data across partitions should have happened at Stage 2. Because here we need to `cogroup`. But to cogroup we need data from `stage 0` and `stage 1`.

So Spark keeps the intermediate results of these stages and then apply it on the `Stage 2`?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You should think of a single "stage" as a series of *transformations* that can be performed on each of the RDD's *partitions* without having to access data in other partitions;

In other words, if I can create an operation T that takes in a single partition and produces a new (single) partition, and apply the same T to each of the RDD's partitions - T can be executed by a single "stage".

Now, `stage 0` and `stage 1` operate on **two separate RDDs** and perform **different transformations**, so they can't share the same stage. Notice that neither of these stages operates on the output of the other - so they are not "candidates" for creating a single stage.

**NOTE** that this doesn't mean they can't run *in parallel*: Spark can schedule both stages to run at the same time; In this case, `stage 2` (which performs the `cogroup`) would wait for both `stage 0` and `stage 1` to complete, produce new partitions, shuffle them to the right executors, and then operate on these new partitions.

Comment: any suggestions please to solve the issue [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47180307/how-to-use-cogroup-for-large-datasets]