# How to get columns of a spark sql query without execution

Tags: scala, apache-spark-sql

I want to extract columns of a spark sql query without executing it. With `parsePlan`:

```
val logicalPlan = spark.sessionState.sqlParser.parsePlan(query)
logicalPlan.collect{
    case p: Project => p.projectList.map(_.name)
}.flatten
```

I was able to extract the list of columns. However it doesn't work in case of `Select *`, and throws an exception with the following message : `An exception or error caused a run to abort: Invalid call to name on unresolved object, tree: *`.

Answer (score 1):

Without any form of execution it is not possible for Spark to determine the columns. For example if a table was loaded from a csv file

```scala
spark.read.option("header",true).csv("data.csv").createOrReplaceTempView("csvTable")
```

then the query

```sql
select * from csvTable
```

would not be able to read the column names without reading (at least the first line) of the csv file.

Extracting a bit of code from Spark's [explain command](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/244405fe57d7737d81c34ba9e8917df6285889eb/sql/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/execution/command/commands.scala#L127) the following lines get as close as possible to an answer to the question:

```scala
val logicalPlan: LogicalPlan = spark.sessionState.sqlParser.parsePlan("select * from csvTable")
val queryExecution: QueryExecution = spark.sessionState.executePlan(logicalPlan)
val outputAttr: Seq[Attribute] = queryExecution.sparkPlan.output
val colNames: Seq[String] = outputAttr.map(a => a.name)
println(colNames)
```

If the file `data.csv` contains the columns `a` and `b` the code prints

```
List(a, b)
```

---

*Disclaimer*: [QueryExecution](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/244405fe57d7737d81c34ba9e8917df6285889eb/sql/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/execution/QueryExecution.scala#L40) is not considered to be a public class that might be used by application developers. As of now (Spark version 2.4.5) the code above works, but it is not guaranteed to work in future versions.

Comment: Thank's your anwser is helpful ! However it does not work when we have complex expressions like a `cast` or an `addition`, it returns the name corresponding to that node (like `CAST(age AS INT) + 1)`, and does not extract the concerned input columns (like `age` here). Is there a way to achieve this ?

Comment: @Sarmon If I understand you correctly, you are looking for the input columns of the DAG. For example, if you look at the picture in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45989409/2129801), you would like to know which columns were part of `newAPIHadoopFile` and `newLogsRDD`. Is this correct?